# PostgreSQL - Detecting patterns in a series

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider the following table:

```
id | date       | status
1  | 2014-01-10 | 1
1  | 2014-02-10 | 1
1  | 2014-03-10 | 1
1  | 2014-04-10 | 1
1  | 2014-05-10 | 0
1  | 2014-06-10 | 0
------------------------
2  | 2014-01-10 | 1
2  | 2014-02-10 | 1
2  | 2014-03-10 | 0
2  | 2014-04-10 | 1
2  | 2014-05-10 | 0
2  | 2014-06-10 | 0
------------------------
3  | 2014-01-10 | 1
3  | 2014-02-10 | 0
3  | 2014-03-10 | 0
3  | 2014-04-10 | 1
3  | 2014-05-10 | 0
3  | 2014-06-10 | 0
------------------------
4  | 2014-01-10 | 0
4  | 2014-02-10 | 1
4  | 2014-03-10 | 1
4  | 2014-04-10 | 1
4  | 2014-05-10 | 0
4  | 2014-06-10 | 0
------------------------
5  | 2014-01-10 | 0
5  | 2014-02-10 | 1
5  | 2014-03-10 | 0
5  | 2014-04-10 | 1
5  | 2014-05-10 | 0
5  | 2014-06-10 | 0
------------------------
```

The Id field is the user id, the date field is when a certain checkpoint is due and the status indicates if the checkpoint is accomplished by its user.

I'm having a big trouble trying to detect users that skipped some checkpoint, like the users with ids 2, 3, 4 and 5. Actually I need a query that lists the id's that have a missing checkpoint in the middle or start of the series, returning only the ids.

I've tried hard to find a way of doing that just with queries, but I couldn't create one. I know that I could do it coding some script, but that project I'm working on requires that I do it just using SQL.

Anyone have a slightest idea on how to accomplish that ?

EDIT: As recommended by the mods here are more details and some things I unsuccessfully tried:

My most successful try was to count how many statuses were registered for each id with this query:

```
SELECT
    id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS check,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS non_check
FROM
    example_table
GROUP BY
    id
ORDER BY
    id
```

Getting the following result:

```
id | check | non_check
1  | 4     | 2
2  | 3     | 3
3  | 2     | 4
4  | 3     | 3
5  | 2     | 4
```

With that result I could select each id entries limiting by it's check result doing a SUM on the status field, if the SUM result is equal with the check result then the checkpoint is contiguous, like in:

```
WITH tbl AS (
    SELECT id, status, SUM(status) AS "sum"
    FROM (
            SELECT id, status FROM example_table WHERE id = 1 ORDER BY date LIMIT 4
        ) AS tbl2
    GROUP BY
            status,id
)
SELECT
    id,"sum"
FROM
    tbl
WHERE
    status = 1
```

Getting the following result:

```
id | sum
1  | 4
```

As the sum result is equal to check on the first query, I can determine that the checkpoints are contiguous. But take the id 2 as an example this time, it's query is:

```
WITH tbl AS (
    SELECT id, status, SUM(status) AS "sum"
    FROM (
            SELECT id, status FROM example_table WHERE id = 2 ORDER BY date LIMIT 3
        ) AS tbl2
    GROUP BY
            status,id
)
SELECT
    id,"sum"
FROM
    tbl
WHERE
    status = 1
```

Notice that I changed the id on WHERE and the LIMIT values based on which id I'm working with and its check result on the first query, and I got the following result:

```
id | sum
2  | 2
```

As the sum field value for id 2 in that query differs from its check value, I can say it's not contiguous. That pattern can be repeated with every id.

As I said before, to work that problem out that way I would need to do it by code, but in that specific case I need it to be in SQL.

Also I found the following article:

[postgres detect repeating patterns of zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534920/postgres-detect-repeating-patterns-of-zeros)

In which the problem resembles mine, but he wants to detect repeating zeroes, it has enlighten me a bit, but not enough to solve my own problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Nahuel Ianni! Maybe that way is better!

Comment: Much better now :) +1 for the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you're looking for is a missed checkpoint followed by an accomplished checkpoint. Join  each checkpoint from a user with the next (by timestamp) checkpoint then look for status 0 joined to status 1.

Here is an example:

```
create table tab (id int,date date,status int);
insert into tab values(1  , '2014-01-10' , 1),(1  , '2014-02-10' , 1),(1  , '2014-03-10' , 1),(1  , '2014-04-10' , 1),(1  , '2014-05-10' , 0),(1  , '2014-06-10' , 0),(2  , '2014-01-10' , 1),(2  , '2014-02-10' , 1),(2  , '2014-03-10' , 0),(2  , '2014-04-10' , 1),(2  , '2014-05-10' , 0),(2  , '2014-06-10' , 0),(3  , '2014-01-10' , 1),(3  , '2014-02-10' , 0),(3  , '2014-03-10' , 0),(3  , '2014-04-10' , 1),(3  , '2014-05-10' , 0),(3  , '2014-06-10' , 0),(4  , '2014-01-10' , 0),(4  , '2014-02-10' , 1),(4  , '2014-03-10' , 1),(4  , '2014-04-10' , 1),(4  , '2014-05-10' , 0),(4  , '2014-06-10' , 0),(5  , '2014-01-10' , 0),(5  , '2014-02-10' , 1),(5  , '2014-03-10' , 0),(5  , '2014-04-10' , 1),(5  , '2014-05-10' , 0),(5  , '2014-06-10' , 0);
with tabwithrow as
    (select *
           , row_number() OVER(PARTITION by id order by date) rnum
        from    tab)
select  *
from    tabwithrow a
join    tabwithrow b on b.rnum = a.rnum + 1
        and a.id = b.id 
        and a.status = 0 
        and b.status = 1;
```

Comment: Sorry if I sound dumb, but how could I do that ?

Comment: SQL fiddle is currently down. I'll provide a demo when it comes back up